# How except works for iterators in Python?

Tags: python, iterator, yield

Can you explain to me why the except clause has never been executed and print never been called in the example?

```
def h(lst):
  try:
    yield from lst
  except StopIteration:
    print('ST')

t = h([1,2])
next(t)
>>> 1
next(t)
>>> 2
next(t)
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-77-f843efe259be>", line 1, in <module>
next(t)

StopIteration
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StopIteration` is thrown by [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), not by the `yield from`:

> `next(iterator[, default])`
>
> Retrieve the next item from the *iterator* by calling its `__next__()` method. If *default* is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise `StopIteration` is raised.

So you could instead wrap the `next` call.

```
def h(lst):
    yield from lst

def next_or_print(it):
    try:
        next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        print('ST')
```

Then you use it like this:

```
>>> t = h([1,2])
>>> next_or_print(t)
1
>>> next_or_print(t)
2
>>> next_or_print(t)
ST
```

Note that `next` also has a second argument that allows to provide a *default* instead of the `StopIteration`:

```
>>> t = h([1,2])
>>> next(t, 'ST')
1
>>> next(t, 'ST')
2
>>> next(t, 'ST')
ST
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `next` calls are **outside** your `h` function and so are not covered by your `try` / `except` clause. For comparison, try this:

```
def h(lst):
    yield from lst

t = h([1,2])
```

Then run repeatedly:

```
try:
    print(next(t))
except StopIteration:
    print('ST')
```

Result:

```
1
2
'ST'
'ST'
'ST'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def h(lst):
  try:
    yield from lst
  except StopIteration:
    print('ST')
t = h([1, 2])
>>> print(t)
<generator object h at 0x7fbf6f08aa40>
```

The function "h" returns a generator. The statement "yield" as a "return" does nothing, only returns a generator. The exception will not be in that part of the code.

The exception must be transferred to another part of the code, where it will work.

```
def h(lst):
    yield from lst
t = h([1, 2])
next(t)
next(t)
try:
    next(t)
except StopIteration:
    print('ST')
ST
```